# PDO number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

This error is returned because of the following code:

```
$statement = $this->db->prepare('
SELECT `Activity`, `Result`, `Time`
FROM `user_activity`
WHERE `Activity` LIKE "%:A%" AND `Time` BETWEEN "2017-:CM-01" AND "2017-:NM-00" AND `Result` = :R AND `UserId` = :ID;');
$statement->execute(
[
    ':A' => $_POST['A'],
    ':CM' => $_POST['CM'],
    ':NM' => $_POST['CM'] + 1,
    ':R' => $_POST['R'],
    ':ID' => $_POST['ID']
]);
```

The error claims I have too few or too many binds, and points at `':ID' => $_POST['ID']`.

I checked the colons, they're all there. I have tried replacing all the parameters in the string, and that works, so there should be an even amount of binds. I even copy-pasted the code in phpMyAdmin ad bound the parameters, and that works!

Is this a syntax problem, or a PDO/PHP thing?

**EDIT**: I found some other questions regarding binding parameters, but I couldn't find one that explained that I couldn't put parameters in strings. This is because I didn't know exactly what I was looking for and couldn't exactly Google for "MySQL parameters in strings" or any of the sort.

Comment: You can't use placeholders like that. They can't exist inside quotes in the query.

Comment: First, you have a misunderstanding about bindings, as demonstrated by `"%:A%"` and `"2017-:CM-01"`.... you need to bind the whole value (with the wildcards, and including the years and day), and let preparing the statement handle the quotes around the value as well

Comment: So `WHERE \`Activity\` LIKE "%:A%" AND \`Time\` BETWEEN "2017-:CM-01" AND "2017-:NM-00"` needs to become `WHERE \`Activity\` LIKE :A AND \`Time\` BETWEEN :CM AND :NM-00`

Comment: And your bindings need to become `[
    ':A' => '%' . $_POST['A'] . '%',
    ':CM' => '2017-' . $_POST['CM'] . '01',
    ':NM' => '2017-' . ($_POST['CM'] + 1) . '01',
    ':R' => $_POST['R'],
    ':ID' => $_POST['ID']
]`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks! Desai's answer was the same so I accepted it.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you, now I actually understand **why** it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your entire query and code like this:

```
<?php
$statement = $this->db->prepare('
SELECT `Activity`, `Result`, `Time`
FROM `user_activity`
WHERE `Activity` LIKE :A AND `Time` BETWEEN :CM AND :NM AND `Result` = :R AND `UserId` = :ID;');
$statement->execute(
[
    ':A' => "%".$_POST['A']."%",
    ':CM' => "2017-".$_POST['CM']."-01",
    ':NM' => "2017-".($_POST['CM'] + 1)."-01",
    ':R' => $_POST['R'],
    ':ID' => $_POST['ID']
]);
```

Comment: :NM would become ```"2017-".($_POST['CM'] + 1)."-00"```, but yes! That seems to work!

Comment: @Fons `00` date???

Comment: Day 0, which excludes the next month itself. Because anything from ```2017-01-01``` till ```2017-02-01``` includes the first of February, which I don't want. And while ```2017-01-31``` works, ```2017-02-31``` doesn't. So getting everything from ```2017-01-01``` till ```2017-02-00``` gets everything in January regardless of the number of days in any given month.